# Context menu command binding fails when forced open

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, command

I am trying to create a button on the interface that give you a dropdown list when clicked for user selection.  A context menu seemed ideal for this except I needed to have it show on left click, not just right.  I put in the following simple code which seemed to work perfectly:

```
Private Sub btn_PredefinedSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    btn.ContextMenu.IsOpen = True
End Sub
```

This just opens the context menu when the button is clicked, which worked great at first.  However now I'm binding to routed commands and running into an issue.  I have it all set up and when I RIGHT click on the button I get the context menu with everything working as expected, but when I LEFT click I get the context menu, but everything is disabled (the availability method simply allows execution at all times so that's not the issue).

Why would it work on right click but not left?  Is there some way to force it to work right?  Or should I be using some other system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried with a simple demo to test this but I remember I encountered this issue before. When right clicking to show the ContextMenu, the `PlacementTarget` is assigned/updated automatically for the ContextMenu. However when left clicking, you have to set the `IsOpen` yourself to popup the ContextMenu, the `PlacementTarget` is not automatically set to the UIElement you click on. So to solve this, just set the `PlacementTarget` yourself like this:

```
Private Sub btn_PredefinedSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
  Dim btn As Button = sender
  btn.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = btn;      
  btn.ContextMenu.IsOpen = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you are my new hero.  Thank you!